# Looking for simple skin node setup

Tags: makehuman, subsurface-scattering

Blender beginner here. I've been trying to find a simple node setup for human skin -- specifically, skin generated from MakeHuman. Almost all setups I could find on the web were either outdated, or quite complex, involving dozens of nodes and numerous textures (bump, displacement, etc.) in addition to the diffuse texture.

The (obviously basic) setup I have right now is this:

[image]

So, my question is: What can I do to improve the above setup, without using additional textures (which I don't have), and without too much additional complexity? Note that photorealism is not required at all; I'm only looking for slight and simple improvements over my current setup.

**Update**: Here's what my character currently looks like:

[image]

The skin already looks good enough for my purposes, but it still looks kind of... flat??

Comment: What’s lacking in your current results? Perhaps add an image of what you’re currently getting along with one of your goal. Depending on what you’re trying to achieve (and at what scale it will be viewed) it could be quite simple or very complicated to setup.

Comment: No clue of your current result or expected result either, makehuman doesn't give much for textures to work with but isn't very difficult to work with. Is something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfqB1.jpg) what you're looking for?

Comment: @RichSedman: Added a render to my post.

Comment: @Timaroberts: Yes, that's what I'm looking for!

Comment: If you don't have extra images textures from makehuman like normal, metallic, specular etc.
You can use a free software which is materialize and will do the textures for you.
It's easy to use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With makehuman textures, you can simply use the [principled node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/shader_nodes/shader/principled.html#principled-bsdf) and feed the [image texture](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/shader_nodes/textures/image.html?#image-texture-node) to color and subsurface scattering inputs.

To provide bump detail, duplicate the texture with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (this keeps it connected to the [mapping node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/shader_nodes/vector/mapping.html#mapping-node)), and add a [color ramp](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/converter/color_ramp.html#color-ramp-node) to create a greyscale image to feed into a [bump node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/shader_nodes/vector/bump.html?#bump-node).

An example of a simple setup could be something like the following:

[image]
<sup>*Click to enlarge*</sup>

This produced the following result from a makehuman export:

[image]